# Sort CSV lines by time in format "Oct 03 10:06:20" in Python

Tags: python, csv, sorting, date

So I have looked for a solution for this but can't seem to find one that works for me.

I have a CSV file in the format:

```
   1 | Thu Oct 04 21:47:53 GMT+01:00 2018 | 35.3254
   2 | Sun Oct 07 09:32:11 GMT+01:00 2018 | 45.7824
   3 | Mon Oct 01 01:00:44 GMT+01:00 2018 | 94.1246

  ...

3023 | Sat Oct 23 01:00:44 GMT+01:00 2018 | 67.2007
```

Unsorted, awkward date and time format.

I want to sort by date and time (there are no column headers, just raw data)

I have used the following code:

```
temp = [] # to hold dates

df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, usecols=[1], engine='c')

for row in df.iterrows():

    # grab date and time only
    new = (repr(row[1]))[9:24]
    temp.append(new)
    temp.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%b %d %H:%M:%S"))

    i = 0
    while i < len(temp):
        print(temp[i])
        i += 1
```

This outputs the date and time in a neater format that is sorted:

```
...

Oct 16 23:25:06
Oct 16 23:29:21
Oct 16 23:34:17
Oct 16 23:40:04
Oct 16 23:44:18
Oct 16 23:49:22
Oct 16 23:54:15
Oct 17 00:00:20
Oct 17 00:05:06
Oct 17 00:09:15
Oct 17 00:14:45
Oct 17 00:19:26

...
```

But I am struggling to write back to the CSV and sort all data by that column.

My desired output is to edit the CSV to get something like:

```
...

456 | Oct 16 23:25:06 | 45.6547
457 | Oct 16 23:29:21 | 64.3453
458 | Oct 16 23:34:17 | 27.6841
459 | Oct 16 23:40:04 | 78.6547
460 | Oct 16 23:44:18 | 11.6547
461 | Oct 16 23:49:22 | 34.6547
462 | Oct 16 23:54:15 | 37.6547
463 | Oct 17 00:00:20 | 68.6547
464 | Oct 17 00:05:06 | 07.6547
465 | Oct 17 00:09:15 | 13.6547
466 | Oct 17 00:14:45 | 37.6547
467 | Oct 17 00:19:26 | 84.6547

...
```

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You could probably do `usecols=[1,2]` and for your print statement `print("{} | {} | {}".format(i, temp[i], df[2][i]))`... (the `while` would need to be unindented).

Answer (score 0):

don't dissociate the date from the rest of your data. Rework your sort key so it takes the 2nd item of your row, and pass the rows to it.

That should do it:

```
result = sorted(df.iterrows(),key=lambda row: datetime.strptime(row[1], "%b %d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: Thanks, does this mean I need to remove usecols=[1] ?

Comment: probably. I couldn't test it fully